# NSFetchRequest of simply filter the relation?

Tags: ios, core-data

Assume a `NSManagedObject` `A` and one `B`. Now `A` has a to-many `B` relationship on `bs`.
Is `[A.bs filter...]` with some `NSPredicate` is very convenient, but likely slower then building up a `NSFetchRequest` on `B` with the same predicate and a condition to match the relation, or am I mistaken?

I guess this performance issue is even worse, if you do something like `lastObject` on the result to obtain only a single result. (The `NSFetchRequest` offers a `fetchLimit` property that can be exploited for this purpose).

On a similar note, if you are just interested in one or two properties, `NSFetchRequest` providers a `propertiesToFetch` property as well.

My reasoning behind this is, that using the relation directly requires core data to pull all `NSManagedObjects` into the relevant `NSManagedObjectContext`. While the `NSFetchRequest` can perform optimizations on the store-level.

Now:

- is my reasoning correct? Thus is the takeaway, that if you are not interested in ***all*** relation objects, go with a `NSFetchRequest`?
- is there a solution to have the convenient (and obviously more readable) approach via the relations having similar performance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your assumption is correct that performance wise fetch requests can use optimizations while the filtering approach is actually a two stage approach where first you fetch all your objects into a NSSet and then send -filteredSetUsingPredicate: to the NSSet which is out of core data's scope already.

One alternative would be to use fetch request templates in your model and instantiate them in your code with [managedObjectModel fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:substitutionVariables:]

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct.

I would add NSFetchRequests offer much more flexibility and opportunities to optimize the requests.

Fetch requests can uses indexes in the underlaying database.
Fetch requests can retrieve objects as faults instead of loading them in full.
Fetch requests can preload some chosen attributes.
They can even perform some operations for you (see NSExpressionDescription, NSExpression).
...

Even if you need to use some in-memory filtering (with objectsWithOptions:passingTest: per example), you better have to use a fetch request to preload the objects and attributes you need. Many fault resolutions will be slower in any case.